# How to add children to the column dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add 4 children or some cases it will be 3 or 2 to the column in the flutter.

```
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[_weatherData],
        )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to add Widget dynamically,

```
  List<Widget> data() {
    List<Widget> list = List();
    //i<5, pass your dynamic limit as per your requirment 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      list.add(Text("Index $i"));//add any Widget in place of Text("Index $i")
    }
    return list;// all widget added now retrun the list here 
  }
```

Now add this list into your column,

```
 Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: data(),
    ),
```

OutPut:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you know beforehand which Widgets you want to add, you can use inline `if` statements when building the children:

```
Column(
     children: <Widget>[
     if(condition1)
      widget1,
     if(condition2)
     widget2,
_    weatherData,
],)
```

or if you do not know beforehand, you can call a function there that returns a `List<Widget>`.

Using the spread operator (`...`) you can even mix and match:

```
Column(
     children: <Widget>[
     if(condition1)
      widget1,
     if(condition2)
     widget2,
_    ..._getWeatherDataWidgets(),
],)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Or if the weatherData() is a Future. You can use FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return Column(
                        children: snapshot.data ?? <Widget>[],
                      );
                    },
                    future: weatherData(),
),
Future<List<Widget>> weatherData() async{
List<Widget> list = await FetchDataFromApi.7Days();
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple children it's simple like below example:

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 0),
                child: new Image.asset('assets/images/blue_dot.png', scale: 1.5,),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 0),
                child: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, color: Color(0Xff004FBA), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 140, top: 0, bottom: 10),
                child: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, color: Color(0Xff767676), fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,),),
              )
          ],
```

Or you can bind child with arrays.